# Query update MySQL is not working with clause IN

Tags: mysql, sql-update

My query is not working though sub-query is working.

```
UPDATE `qan_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = 'NEW' WHERE `meta_id` IN (SELECT `meta_id` FROM `qan_postmeta` WHERE `meta_value` = 'OLD')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about performance, never use a query like

```
UPDATE qan_postmeta SET meta_value = NEW WHERE meta_id IN (SELECT meta_id FROM qan_postmeta WHERE meta_value = OLD)
```

MySQL does not optimize this and seems to scan the temporary table, which isn't indexed, for every row in the update statement. This applies to other statements than `UPDATE` as well.

Instead, either use a `JOIN` like

```
UPDATE qan_postmeta INNER JOIN qan_postmeta ON qan_postmeta.meta_id = meta_id SET meta_value = NEW WHERE meta_value = OLD
```

Be aware that MySQL can take many but not too many arguments. Passing a list of 100'000 arguments to an `IN` statement won't work.

Source: http://makandracards.com/makandra/2681-mysql-do-not-use-where-id-in-select

Comment: you miss alias. Althought It was resolved. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
UPDATE tab_1 a
  JOIN tab_2 b 
    ON a.meta_id=b.meta_id
  SET a.meta_value='new'
WHERE b.meta_value='old';
```

Comment: and whats the difference in this?:)

Comment: none, but when I write my replay was no answer, I was slower :))) I am new here should I delete my answer?

Comment: there is no need to delete it, i was just curious if I was missing something:)